# screens in blackberry

Tags: user-interface, blackberry

how can i navigate screens on button click.
there are two buttons , previous and next.
when i click the previous button, a screan1  will be displayed and when i press next ,a screan2  will be displayed and so on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a couple of different ways to do this. The UI library on a Blackberry will maintain a stack of screens for you so you can either:

1) when a button is pressed, create a new screen and push it onto the stack, then remove the old screen and let it be garbage collected; or

2) when a button is pressed, determine if a screen for that button already exists on the stack and move it to the front, or create a new one as above. In this case you don't have to remove the screens, but if you have a lot of complex screens you could run out of resources.

See: net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication.pushScreen(Screen screen) and net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication.popScreen(Screen screen)

Answer (score 0):

Here's a simple implementation:

```
import net.rim.device.api.ui.Field;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.FieldChangeListener;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.UiApplication;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.ButtonField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.component.LabelField;
import net.rim.device.api.ui.container.MainScreen;

public class NavigateScreen extends MainScreen implements FieldChangeListener {

    private ButtonField previousButton;
    private ButtonField nextButton;

    public NavigateScreen() {
        add(new LabelField("Some content"));

        previousButton = new ButtonField("Previous", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        previousButton.setChangeListener(this);

        nextButton = new ButtonField("Next", ButtonField.CONSUME_CLICK);
        nextButton.setChangeListener(this);

        add(previousButton);
        add(nextButton);
    }

    public void fieldChanged(Field field, int context) {
        if (field == previousButton) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(NavigateScreen.this);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new PreviousScreen());
        }
        if (field == nextButton) {
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(NavigateScreen.this);
            UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new NextScreen());
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi I have created a SwitchScreenController class to make switching between screen very easly.

```
public class SwitchScreenController {

public void switchHomeScreen() {

}

public void switchToHomeScreen() {
    //UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new HomeScreen());
}

public void switchToProgressingScreen() {
}

public void switchToNextScreen(MainScreen targetScreen) {
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(targetScreen);
}

public void switchToPreviousScreen() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(
           UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
}

}
```

you can use it any where like this.

```
new 
public class SwitchScreenController {

public void switchHomeScreen() {

}

public void switchToHomeScreen() {
    //UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(new HomeScreen());
}

public void switchToProgressingScreen() {
}

public void switchToNextScreen(MainScreen targetScreen) {
    UiApplication.getUiApplication().pushScreen(targetScreen);
}

public void switchToPreviousScreen() {
        UiApplication.getUiApplication().popScreen(
           UiApplication.getUiApplication().getActiveScreen());
}

}
```

you can go back using

```
new SwitchScreenController().switchToPreviousScreen();
```

and to next screen using

```
new SwitchScreenController().switchToNextScreen(new NextScreen());
```